# Angular4: How to locate a component based on a value of a variable

Tags: angular, listener

Let's suppose I have 10 div elements and on special elements that has to be placed inside on of the 10 divs.

At first, I thought to hold a service that has an attribute (named 'location' that determines in what div element this special element should be. So, each one of these div elements will have a template:

```
<div [num] = "num"> 
   <div *ngIf = "num == service.location"> Special</div>
</div>
```

In this case each div element will have to read the location attribute from the service, which is inefficient.

However, I thought whether it can be done more efficiently. I thought about putting some kind of listener/observer on the variable 'location' and whenever it changes, the special element will be placed inside the appropriate element. In this case, I can do it with a complexity of O(1).

Do you know any Angular technique that can help me do it?

Comment: why not put your 10 elements as an array of objects so can use `*ngFor` along with something like `{special:true}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. add an special attribute to a specific div
2. after that query all these divs (with dummy child-directive just as a marker)
3. after that in ngAfterViewInit find one with special attribute.

   ```
   @Directive({selector: '[child-directive]'})
   export class ChildDirective {
   }

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       <div>
         <div child-directive>Hi</div>
         <div child-directive [attr.special]="test">special</div>
         <div child-directive>Hi</div>
       </div>
     `,
   })
   export class App implements AfterViewInit {
     @ViewChildren(ChildDirective, {read: ElementRef}) children: QueryList<ElementRef>;
     test = true;

     constructor() {
     }

     ngAfterViewInit() {
       const special = this.children.find(el=> {
         let native = el.nativeElement;
         if(native.getAttribute("special")) {
           return true;
         }
         else {
           return false;
         }
       });
       console.log(special);
     }
   }
   ```